# Encrypting a drive while hiding amount of data with multiple file systems in Linux?

Tags: linux, encryption, disk-encryption

Is there a way to encrypt a drive in a way that an attacker can't tell how much data is on it?

It would also need to be able to hold multiple independent file-systems so you can safely share one key without revealing the other data.
And an attacker should not be able to tell how many encrypted file-systems there are.

Is this possible with Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than one option, the easiest one is to use an unencrypted file system and store encrypted image files on it, that can be used with the `cryptoloop` block device. This way you can add or delete encrypted volumes with just `dd` and `losetup` resp. `rm`.

Of course you can also use `LUKS` and friends, but this is a bit more advanced. Encrypted loop devices can hold any file system and the properties of AES encryption make it a default, that the amount of data in each file system can't be read without the key, as long a you make sure you don't use sparse files (and even then the attack is very theoretical).

**EDIT**

Just to make that absolutely clear: The size of each image file is constant (as is the size of a physical partition). It is predetermined the same way, as a partition size is.

To hide the amount of file systems you habe two choices:

- Create a single encrypted image file and write the other image files into it (again encrypted or plain, according to your needs)
- Fill the remaining space with dummy image files - nobody can tell, which of those contains valid data and which does not

Comment: How does this hide the amount of encrypted data? The size of the images will vary depending on the amount of data stored in them. Also I forgot to mention this in my question but I want the amount of file systems to be hidden, so an attacker can't tell how many file systems are on the drive.

Comment: The size of the images will **not** vary at all if you do not use sparse files - just as the physical size of your harddisk doesn't change with the amount of data stored in it. An image file is just "a disk stored in a file"

Comment: Is it possible to hide the amount of file-systems while still providing access to one of the file-systems? For example letting somebody access a decoy file-system while hiding the real one?

Comment: Of corse - the decoys do not really differ from the real ones, they just hold no (or fake) data, So you could create a pair, one being a decoy with (fake but deniably so) data, the other a real one with the secret data and different keys. Giving out the fake key allows the observer to see the fake data, but not the real one

Comment: Wouldn't the real file-system also appear as an image file in the first encrypted image? So if we grant the attacker access to the first encrypted image wouldn't he see the real file-system too?

Comment: He would see the image file, but not its contents

Comment: The key word is Steganography. It's supported by encrypted filesystem tools such as [Veracrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Hidden%20Volume.html).